# how to check if the char in a string is the same as the previous char?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

The problem asks to compare if the string has consecutive same letters and rewrite it as the number of the letter plus the letter, for example, AAAAA as in 5A. But when I use the if statement to make the comparison the output become some very long number instead of the desired result.

Here is a portion of the problem:
Run-length encoding is a simple compression scheme best used when a dataset consists primarily of numerous, long runs of repeated characters. For example, AAAAAAAAAA is a run of 10 A’s. We could encode this run using a notation like *A10, where the * is a special flag character that indicates a run, A is the symbol in the run, and 10 is the length of the run.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunLengthEncoding {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter input string: ");
    String s = input.nextLine();
    for (int a = 0; a < s.length(); a++) {
        if ((s.charAt(a) < 'A' || s.charAt(a) > 'Z')) {
            System.out.print("Bad input");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Enter flag character: ");
    char flag = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (flag == '#' || flag == '$' || flag == '*' || flag == '&') {

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i)=s.charAt(i-1));
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
            if (count == 2)
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i));
            if (count == 3)
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i));
            else
                System.out.print(flag + s.charAt(i) + (count + 1));

        }

    } else
        System.out.print("Bad input");
}
}
```

Comment: There is a ; behind your if (before the count++). Is that your problem?
Edit: Also i recomment to always use brackets for the if statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(s.charAt(i)=s.charAt(i-1));
```

First of all, you must compare `char`s using `==` not `=`. Second, putting a `;` right after the `if` statement will cause it to terminate immediately. In other words, the following line is no longer part of the `if` statement. Change to:

```
if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i-1))
```

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, something like this should work, though I didn't test it. Just replace your current large `if` block with the below:

```
if (flag == '#' || flag == '$' || flag == '*' || flag == '&') {
    char last = ' ';
    char curr = ' ';
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        last = curr;
        curr = s.charAt(i);
        if (curr == last) {
            count++;
        } else if (last != ' ') {
            System.out.print(("" + count) + last);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(("" + count) + last);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem, but the result is still incorrect.For example, when I enter AAAAAABBBBB the result is supposed to be 6A5B, but the actual output is A followed by some number. can you tell me how to fix this

Comment: @HongxuLin In Java, a `char` value is a number, so `s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i)` is adding the unicode value of the two characters to produce a number. It is not doing string concatenation, which is what you're trying to do. Same with `flag + s.charAt(i) + (count + 1)`, which is adding 3 numbers together.

Comment: @HongxuLin see my edit. Please remember to upvote and accept if this helps.

Comment: It worked but the program only counts the number of the first letter then stop.I tested it by entering AAAAABBBBB but it displays 1 5A. how to make it continue to count the following letter and how to get rid of the 1 in front.

Comment: @HongxuLin Sorry about that, fixed it. Tested it out myself. Works perfectly this time.